# Extract Types based on Tuple to new Tuple

Tags: typescript

Assuming that I have a tuple of strings:

```
const tuple = ["a", "b", ..., "n"] as const;
```

which are mapped to the entries of a certain Type:

```
type MyType = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  ...
  n: N;
```

How do I extract the type located at `Mytype[typeof tuple[number]]` to a new tuple resulting in:

```
type MyTypeToTuple = [Mytype[tuple[0]], Mytype[tuple[1]], ... , Mytype[tuple[n]]]
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mapped types to turn tuples into tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  Unfortunately, the following straightforward implementation won't work:

```
type MyTuple = typeof tuple;

type Oops = { [K in keyof MyTuple]: MyType[MyTuple[K]] } // error
// -------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'readonly ["a", "b", "n"][K]' cannot be used to index type 'MyType'.(2536)
//
/* type Oops = {
    [x: number]: string | number | N;
    readonly 0: string;
    readonly 1: number;
    readonly 2: N;
    length: unknown;
    toString: unknown;
    toLocaleString: unknown; ... */
```

That's because of a bug or limitation in TypeScript whereby the tuple/array mapping isn't triggered on specific tuple types like `MyTuple`; see [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995).  For now, you need to do it on an unspecified generic type parameter like `T extends MyTuple`, and even then the compiler cannot understand that the `K` in `T[K]` only includes the numeric indices and therefore that `T[K] extends keyof MyType`.  Thus, instead of `MyType[T[K]]` you need something like `MyType[Extract<T[K], keyof MyType>]` with [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to calm the compiler's worries.  Thus we have the two-line definition:

```
type MapToMyType<T> = { [K in keyof T]: MyType[Extract<T[K], keyof MyType>] };

type MyTypeToTuple = MapToMyType<typeof tuple>
// type MyTypeToTuple = readonly [string, number, /*...*/ N]
```

Which is now the type you want.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHLIN7JALmQZzClAHNkBfAKEoQHsRDkwBXABwBsUBeZAbQCI4-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-mVUFEcgiqjQmiAA)

Comment: Thanks, was stuck on the "Oops"-approach. Works perfectly fine.